# A module __init__.py from a folder cannot import the modules in that folder

Tags: python, import, wxpython

Using python 3. I am trying to experiment with a wxpython module "aui"

I copied aui folder from wxPython-src-3.0.2.0\wxPython\wx\lib\agw\aui into my project directory

For example:

```
/aui (Folder)

    __init__.py 
    aui_constants.py
    aui_switcherdialog.py
    ...
    ...
    tabmdi.py

myfile.py
```

In myfile.py, I tried simply

```
import aui
```

__init__.py which in turn tries:

```
from aui_constants import *
from aui_utilities import *
from auibar import *
```

...but raises import error from even they are in the same folder as __init__.py

```
from aui_constants import *
ImportError: No module named 'aui_constants'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a relative import

You can import using `from .aui_constants import *` and likewise for your other import statements.